# Angular4 - 3 level custom components, grandchild (ngModelChange) always sees same grandparent

Tags: angular, components, onchange

I have a top-level component that has this in the template:

```
  <cw-card-list [cards]="cards">
  </cw-card-list>
```

The cards are populated from the API when the component loads:

```
  private getCards(): void{
    this._cardService.getCards().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.cards = result;
      }
    );
  }
```

The card-list component is very basic:

```
  <div *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index">
    <cw-card-list-item
      [card]="card" [index]="i">
    </cw-card-list-item>
  </div>
```

You can see that each card in the list is an Input in the card-list-item child:

```
export class CardListItemComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() card: Card;
  @Input() index: number;
...
```

Finally, each of these list-item components also has a child:

```
<cw-checklist-show [template]="card.template" 
</cw-checklist-show>

export class ChecklistShowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() template: Template
...
```

Everything works, all the data is displayed.

However, inside this final component there is a checkbox, which is bound to a property 'is_completed' of each child (a TemplateItem):

```
<div *ngFor="let child of template.template_items; let i=index">
          <input id="checkbox-{{i}}" type="checkbox" 
            [ngModel]="child.is_completed"
            (ngModelChange)="onItemIsCompletedChange(i)">
</div>
```

Every time the (ngModelChange) event fires it always amends the 'is_completed' property of the Template for the **first card** in the list, not the one clicked on.

Why is that happening? I even tried wiring up an output event to the parent and console logged the template - and it always lists the same Template, item [0] in the card list array!

But if I console.log `this.cards` in the grandparent, it shows the correct Template is attached to each Card!

**DATA STRUCTURE**

Each Card has a Template, like this:

```
import { Template } from './template';
export class Card {
  constructor() {
  }

  public id: string
  public customer_id: string
  public template: Template
  public follow_up: Date
  public is_new: boolean = true
}
```

Each Template has an array of TemplateItem:

```
import { TemplateItem } from './template-item';

export class Template {
  constructor(
  ) {}

  public id: string
  public account_id: string
  public name: string
  public template_items: Array<TemplateItem>
  public template_type: string
  public status: string
}
```

Each TemplateItem is like this:

```
export class TemplateItem {
  constructor(
  ) {}

  public id: string
  public template_id: string
  public sort: number
  public content: string
  public item_type: string
  public is_completed: boolean = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps not immediately obvious if you are used to building model driven forms, as I am, but the ID of the input is crucially important.

Since my inputs were using the INDEX, it means that the checkboxes on my page did not have different ids:

```
checkbox-{{i}}
```

This means that clicking it always fires the event on the checkboxes in the first card (eg checkbox-0, checkbox-1) since obviously each grandchild (TemplateItem) is an array from 0...n.

So the solution is:

```
      <input id="checkbox-{{child.id}}-{{i}}" type="checkbox" 
        [ngModel]="child.is_completed"
        (ngModelChange)="onItemIsCompletedChange(i)">
```

Now each checkbox has a unique id, specific to the id of the grandchild TemplateItem.